# Linux split separate files on disk but see as one

Tags: command-line, files

Is there is a functionality in Linux that allows you to reference multiple files as one?

For example:

`linux.txt.0`, `linux.txt.1`, `linux.txt.2`, `linux.txt.3` can be seen as separate files or as `linux.txt`

A useful example:

```
echo linux.txt
```

should print the contents of `linux.txt.0`, `linux.txt.1`, `linux.txt.2`, `linux.txt.3` in that particular order.

I don't want to use `cat` with multiple arguments because it loads the files in memory and usually my files are huge.

Comment: `cat` doesn't load entire files into memory. It's not a text editor.

Comment: How does it send the content of the file in pipe without loading all its content?

Comment: By allocating a small buffer, reading into that buffer and then writing out the contents. The buffer will be *much* smaller than your file size.

Comment: If you would look at [cat](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cat.c?id=v8.23) source code from GNU coreutils 8.23, you would see that the files are read in chunks which are most of the time [128 KiB](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ioblksize.h?id=v8.23#n23) (unless the blocksize for file system I/O returned [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) is bigger).

Comment: Btw, `echo linux.txt` would never display the contents of files, it would just display `linux.txt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do that kind of thing is to use the shell's globbing and/or brace expansion features:

```
cat linux.{0..3}.txt
```

or

```
cat linux.*.txt
```

As others have explained, `cat` does not load the whole file into memory, it will just read a few bytes from it, print them to screen and repeat until everything has been read.